# IPython: redirecting output of a Python script to a file (like bash >)

Tags: python, io, ipython

I have a Python script that I want to run in IPython. I want to redirect (write) the output to a file, similar to:

```
python my_script.py > my_output.txt
```

How do I do this when I run the script in IPython, i.e. like `execfile('my_script.py')`

There is an [older page](http://rcjp.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/redirecting-stdout-within-ipython/) describing a function that could be written to do this, but I believe that there is now a built-in way to do this that I just can't find.

Comment: looks like missing feature, it should be simpler than answers below to be practical

Answer (score 50, accepted):

IPython has its own context manager for [capturing stdout/err](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/rel-0.13.1/IPython/utils/io.py#L359), but it doesn't redirect to files, it redirects to an object:

```
from IPython.utils import io
with io.capture_output() as captured:
    %run my_script.py

print captured.stdout # prints stdout from your script
```

And this functionality is exposed in a `%%capture` cell-magic, as illustrated in the [Cell Magics example notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/ipython/ipython/master/examples/notebooks/Cell%20Magics.ipynb).

It's a simple context manager, so you can write your own version that would redirect to files:

```
class redirect_output(object):
    """context manager for reditrecting stdout/err to files"""


    def __init__(self, stdout='', stderr=''):
        self.stdout = stdout
        self.stderr = stderr

    def __enter__(self):
        self.sys_stdout = sys.stdout
        self.sys_stderr = sys.stderr

        if self.stdout:
            sys.stdout = open(self.stdout, 'w')
        if self.stderr:
            if self.stderr == self.stdout:
                sys.stderr = sys.stdout
            else:
                sys.stderr = open(self.stderr, 'w')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        sys.stdout = self.sys_stdout
        sys.stderr = self.sys_stderr
```

which you would invoke with:

```
with redirect_output("my_output.txt"):
    %run my_script.py
```

Comment: You could make this a little more robust by capturing *args and **kw in the `__init__` method and passing them to open, rather than hardcoding write mode.

Answer (score 16):

To quickly store text contained in a variable while working in IPython use [`%store`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html) with `>` or `>>`:

`%store VARIABLE >>file.txt`  (appends)

`%store VARIABLE >file.txt` (overwrites)

(Make sure there is no space immediately following the `>` or `>>`)

Comment: I have `ERROR:root:Line magic function '%store' not found.` when run it from `PyDev console: using IPython 6.0.0`. The same call in `ipython3` works well.

Comment: If you get a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''`, you might try without a space after `>` or `>>`, like so:
`%store VARIABLE >file.txt`

Answer (score 3):

While this an old question, I found this and the answers as I was facing a similar problem.

The solution I found after sifting through [IPython Cell magics documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-sc) is actually fairly simple. At the most basic the solution is to assign the output of the command to a variable.

This simple two-cell example shows how to do that. In the first Notebook cell we define the Python script with some output to `stdout` making use of the `%%writefile` cell magic.

```py
%%writefile output.py
print("This is the output that is supposed to go to a file")
```

Then we run that script like it was run from a shell using the `!` operator.

```py
output = !python output.py
print(output)
>>> ['This is the output that is supposed to go to a file']
```

Then you can easily make use of the `%store` magic to persist the output.

```py
%store output >output.log
```

Notice however that the output of the command is persisted as a list of lines. You might want to call `"\n".join(output)` prior storing the output.

Answer (score 2):

For just one script to run I would do the redirection in bash

```
ipython -c "execfile('my_script.py')" > my_output.txt
```

On **python 3**, execfile does not exist any more, so use this instead

```
ipython -c "exec(open('my_script.py').read())" > my_output.txt
```

Be careful with the double vs single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

use this code to save the output to file

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import sys
#write the stdout to file
def log():
    #for stop the thread
    global run
    while (run):
        try:
            global out
            text = str(sys.stdout.getvalue())
            with open("out.txt", 'w') as f:
                f.write(text)
        finally:
            time.sleep(1)
```

```
%%capture out
run = True
print("start")
process = Thread(target=log, args=[]).start()

# do some work
for i in range(10, 1000):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
run= False
process.join()
```

It is useful to use a text editor that tracer changes the file and suggest reloading the file like
[notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why the verified solution doesn't entirely work in a loop, the following:

```
for i in range(N):
    with redirect_output("path_to_output_file"):
        %run <python_script> arg1 arg2 arg3
```

creates N files in the directory with only output from the first print statement of the <python_script>. Just confirming- when run separately for each iteration of the for loop, the script produces the right result.

Answer (score -1):

There's the hacky way of overwriting `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` with a file object, but that's really not a good way to go about it.  Really, if you want to control where the output goes from inside python, you need to implement some sort of logging and/or output handling system that you can configure via the command line or function arguments instead of using `print` statements.

Answer (score -1):

It seems a lot of code....
My solution.
[redirect output of ipython script into a csv or text file like sqlplus spool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029938/redirect-output-of-ipython-script-into-a-csv-or-text-file-like-sqlplus-spool)
wonder there is an easy way like oracle sqlplus spool command..?