# Tensorflow: why doesn't tensorflow print each value in this loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was going through some Tensorflow code that runs a `tf.while_loop()` and I had a question. The code calculates the roots of a 4th degree polynomial as part of a lab for learning `tensorflow.` My question is why a specific print statement will not output all of the intermediate values.

The code is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def f(x, w):
    return (w[0] + w[1] * x + w[2] * tf.pow(x,2) + w[3] * tf.pow(x,3) + w[4] * tf.pow(x,4) )

def f1(x, w):
    return (w[1] + 2. * w[2] * x + 3. * w[3] * tf.pow(x,2) + 4. * w[4] * tf.pow(x,3) )

def f2(x, w):
    return (2. * w[2] + 6. * w[3] * x + 12. * w[4] * tf.pow(x,2) )

def fxn_plus_1(xn, w):
    return (xn - (2. * f(xn, w) * f1(xn, w) / (2. * tf.square(f1(xn, w)) - f(xn, w) * f2(xn, w))))

def c(x, weights):
    return tf.abs(x - fxn_plus_1(x, weights)) > 0.001

def b(x, weights):
    x = fxn_plus_1(x, weights)
    return x, weights

weights = tf.constant( [-1000., 1., 1. , 5. , 0.1])

x = fxn_plus_1(-10., weights)

out = tf.while_loop(c, b, [x, weights])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x, weights = sess.run(out)
    print(x)
```

The output is correct with a values of `5.575055`. Now, I wanted to see what the intermediate values were of the loop body `b()` as the algorithm proceeded. I changed the function `b()` to the following:

```
def b(x, weights):
    x = fxn_plus_1(x, weights)
    print(x) ## ADDED PRINT STATEMENT
    print(weights)
    return x, weights
```

What I get in return is:

```
Tensor("while_4/sub_4:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
Tensor("while_4/Identity_1:0", shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
5.575055
```

this seems to give the debug output or the graph information for the values of `x,weights` instead of the actual values. I was not sure how to get the loop to actually print the values at each step.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

UPDATE on things attempted and suggested:

One of the commentors @user49593, suggested I try using `tf.Print()`.

Here is the code, and the output. I am still just getting the graph info instead of the actual vector of values.

```
def b(x, weights):
    x = fxn_plus_1(x, weights)
    x = tf.Print(x, [x], message="here: ") #CHANGED TO tf.Print STATEMENT
    return x, weights
```

The output is still just `5.575055`. No vector of intermediate values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the value of a Tensor object in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow)

Comment: @user49593 Thanks for checking, but I think this is a different issue. I read the link, and it suggests using the `eval()` method. But that is used if you are evaluating a function inside of a `with tf.Session() as sess:`. In the OP, the point is that the print statement in the `b()` function is setup before the session context, but that print statement is called from within the session context. I tried using `eval()` and got an error.

Comment: Did you try using `tf.Print()` as mentioned? "To print the value of a tensor without returning it to your Python program, you can use the tf.Print() operator"

Comment: I did try `tf.Print()` but it is still just giving me the graph output instead of the actual values. I can update the OP with the output I get when using `tf.Print()`. Yeah, it is just confusing why this issue seems so confusing. I am used to the tricks that you mentioned when trying to debug in the `sess.run()` but these are functions called within `sess.run()`.

Comment: That's not how you use `tf.Print()`. Do `x = tf.Print(x, [x], message="here: ")`

[Using tf.Print blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-tf-print-in-tensorflow-aa26e1cff11e)

Comment: Sorry about that. I changed the code to exactly as you suggested, but still no change in the output. I will update the OP.

Comment: Are you doing this in a jupyter notebook by any chance?

Comment: I am actually doing this oon google Colab. I have an jupyter notebook open there. I can share it with you? Would that make sense.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can't do `tf.Print()` in jupyter - it just doesn't output anything

Comment: Interesting, I had not heard that. You think I should try and run it in Tensorboard and see if I can see intermediate results there? I found this on the jupyter issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898478/is-there-a-way-to-get-tensorflow-tf-print-output-to-appear-in-jupyter-notebook-o

Comment: @user49593 Hey, thanks for the tip about notebooks. Turns out that the code works when I run the the code as a file, but not when I run it in a notebook. But glad that it was not something more exotic.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question, was really found by @user49593. The problem is that the Jupyter Notebooks don't show the output of the print statements. So in order to see the output, you need to put the code into a file and then run it from the command line.

So if I wrap up the code above into a file named `equation.py`. Then I would go to the command line and type.

```
python equation.py
```

This will generate the expected output. Looks like there is another SE post related to this, which might have some additional insights.

[Is there a way to get tensorflow tf.Print output to appear in Jupyter Notebook output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898478/is-there-a-way-to-get-tensorflow-tf-print-output-to-appear-in-jupyter-notebook-o)