# redirect output of ipython script into a csv or text file like sqlplus spool

Tags: python, ipython

I try to redirect the output of my script to a file.
I don't want to do something like

```
python myscript.py > xy.out
```

as a lot of the variable is being stored in my ipython environment and I like to carry it over.

I try to follow this link

[IPython: redirecting output of a Python script to a file (like bash >)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571090/ipython-redirecting-output-of-a-python-script-to-a-file-like-bash)

however, when I try to do

```
with redirect_output("my_output.txt"):
    %run my_script.py
```

It gives the error

```
---> 10         self.sys_stdout = sys.stdout
NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined
```

There is a similar solution to copy the output of a ipython shell to a file but It says my cell its not defined

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-export-the-output-of-the-IPython-command-to-a-text-file-or-a-CSV-file

Is there a easier way or build in feature with ipython that does that ??
e.g.

In oracle sqlplus there is a spool command 
e.g.

```
spool /tmp/abc
select * from table_x;
spool off
```

now the sql statement output is in /tmp/abc

Is such a equivalent for ipython ??

Comment: Did you `import sys`, before trying the `redirect_output` function?

Answer (score 1):

Greeting. I end up using this solution:

```
%%capture var2
%run -I script2

import sys
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = file('out5.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f 
print var2
stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

It is not very handy but it works!

Comment: From what I understand, this will wait till the end of your code, and then dump it into the file. Is that what you were expecting? The advantage of the `redirect_output` function, as far as I can see is that it will write to the file as the output is generated.. so you can see the output in the log file in real time...

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import sys
#write the stdout to file
def log():
    #for stop the thread
    global run
    while (run):
        try:
            global out
            text = str(sys.stdout.getvalue())
            with open("out.txt", 'w') as f:
                f.write(text)
        finally:
            time.sleep(1)
```

```
%%capture out
run = True
print("start")
process = Thread(target=log, args=[]).start()

# do some work
for i in range(10, 1000):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
run= False
process.join()
```