# Write print statements including errors/warnings to file in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I have a big python script where multiple print statements and warnings (e.g. deprecation warnings) are being printed to the IPython console. For debugging purposes I want to write all print statements and warnings/error to an output file. Is there a way to do this in Spyder?

I have tried in the console (but it won't create an output file in any of my directories):

```
runfile('pyfile.py',wdir='wdir') > output.txt
```

I know how to do this in the prompt:

```
python "directory\pyfile.py"> output.txt 2>&1
```

But being able to do this in Spyder would be way more convenient. I have conducted an extensive search here on Stack Overflow but none of the answers to previous questions gave me the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to be aware that Spyder uses *IPython* consoles to run your code, so it's always better to search for what things you can do in IPython instead of in Spyder.

In this case, searching for [`ipython save stdout`](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=3eL&channel=fs&q=ipython+save+stdout) gave me the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14573397/438386) in the first result, and that's an StackOverflow one.

In essence, you need to use the `%%capture` magic or a context manager (as the one mentioned in the answer above) and put `runfile` inside one of them to capture all stdout output in your program.