# Suppress any output from imported notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm new to Jupyter notebooks but a python developer, so it seems obvious to me to split my long complex code in different modules, that in this case are notebooks.

I have:

- `notebook1.ipynb`

  - In here I import the data, and make data cleaning
  - This produces outputs, there are many print functions
- `notebook2.ipynb`

  - analysis and charts

As one of the first thing in **notebook2** I import the other one:

```
%run notebook1.ipynb
```

This will correctly import and run the notebook as well as put all variables in scope.  But it will also *print everything that was printed from notebook1*.

**QUESTION: Is there a way to suppress the output of external jupyter notebooks?**

Comment: if you don't what to display it then don't use `print()`

Comment: [IPython: redirecting output of a Python script to a file (like bash >)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571090/ipython-redirecting-output-of-a-python-script-to-a-file-like-bash)

Comment: I want to use print when cleaning my data on notebook1. Once it's done I won't work on notebook1 anymore, just run it via notebook2, and in this case I don't care anymore about the print.

Comment: in link above there is code which redirects output to variable before using `%run` - maybe it can help